# How to make python script run in pypy also being executable via pyinstaller?

Tags: python, performance, optimization

So the thing is I want to make my python code run faster, also i want to make it executable via pyinstaller. Is it any possibility to create .exe file with python code run on pypy?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps mentioned in https://datatofish.com/executable-pyinstaller/ to create .exe file under the "Steps to Create an Executable from Python Script using Pyinstaller" section.

Comment: Thre thing is i know how to do that in cpython, but is any possibility to use pyinstaller and also pypy version of python?